# Why I can't receive a notification on an observer class inside a View struct in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, nsnotificationcenter

I have the following code, where I create a class that acts as an observer of a default notification. But the notification never arrives:

```
struct NotificationCenterExampleView: View {
    
    let observerA = ObserverClassA()
    
    init() {
        print("NotificationCenterExampleView init")
        
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(observerA, selector: #selector(ObserverClassA.receivedNotification(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("CustomNotification"), object: "This is the message")
        let notificationToPost = Notification(name: Notification.Name("CustomNotification"), object: "Message being sent", userInfo: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(notificationToPost)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Notification Center Example")
            .frame(minWidth: 250, maxWidth: 500, minHeight: 250, maxHeight: 500)
    }
}

class ObserverClassA: NSObject {
    
    @objc func receivedNotification(notification: Notification) {
        let message = notification.object as! String
        print("Message received: \(message)")
    }
}
```

I know that using `.publisher` and `onReceive` this will work inside the View struct, but what's the actual reason for this code to not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notifications matched by object, so if you subscribe by one object but post with another object, then subscriber is not fired.

Here is fixed variant. Tested with Xcode 12.1.

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(observerA, 
       selector: #selector(ObserverClassA.receivedNotification(notification:)), 
       name: Notification.Name("CustomNotification"), 
       object: nil)   // << subscribe for all

    let notificationToPost = Notification(name: Notification.Name("CustomNotification"), object: "This is the message", userInfo: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.post(notificationToPost)
```